# GitX: reset master to here

Tags: git, repository, reset, local, master

I'm using GitX to work with a Git repository for a project. Somehow, things got out of sync and although I can pull the latest changes, I can't commit anything because it thinks there is an unresolved conflict in a particular file. Yet, when I resolve the conflict, the file disappears from the staging view, so I can't commit it and end up back where I was.

What I want to do is just pull all the latest changes from the repo and *discard* any and all of my local changes, so that my local copy is exactly identical to the repo. I have only made a few simple changes, and would rather just make them again (once everything is in sync) then continue to go in circles trying to merge.

I'm thinking a "reset master to here" on the latest commit and switching the toggle to "hard" would do the trick:

> Resets the index and working tree. Any changes to tracked files in the working tree are discarded. **Warning! This discards all changes. It may be hard to recover them.**

I just want to be sure that this is referring to my *local* changes being discarded. Is that correct? Would this update my local to an exact mirror of what's in the repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get an exact mirror of the origin, without any local changes, you may just delete your local repo and type 'git clone '.

Unfortunately, GitX is not a replacement for command-line git, but an addon to a subset of functions the latter provides.

Yes, the hard reset you have mentioned does the trick as well,